# Thumbnail Navigation Issue With Click Events

Tags: html, swiper.js

I have an issue with thumbnail image Swiper.

**Expected Behavior**

When I click on a thumbnail, it should immediately change the slide of the main slider to the index of the clicked thumbnail.

**Actual Behavior**

When I click on a thumbnail, it takes 2-3 times to trigger click event. It appears that there is something impeding the propagation of click events in thumbnail controlled sliders. However, when I use the next/prev buttons on the main slider, the thumbnails are working fine.

Here's the demo currently on your site.
http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/300-thumbs-gallery.html

Github issue:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/2934

What might cause this behavior and how can I fix it?

Comment: Fix typos & improve readability

Comment: Any fix for this? I have the same problem!

Comment: Thank @HelderSepulveda.
Yes, see my below anser JasonBiondo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, in Swiper have option is `threshold`, you can set it in thumbnail carousel biger than 10

Swiper API: https://swiperjs.com/api/

Comment: I spent over an hour on this issue, it's working for me - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you added `threshold` and it still doesn't work remove param `allowTouchMove={false}`.

That's should help.